# Python Social Auth Django installation failure

Tags: python, django, pip, ubuntu-14.04, social-auth-app-django

I am trying to install Python Social Auth for Django, but it is not succesful.

Server OS: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab141.3 x86_64)

Python version: 3.4.3

Django version (if it matters): 2.0.8

I use `pip install social-auth-app-django`, and the installation is starting, but after a while I get some errors.

```
...
Building wheels for collected packages: cffi
  Building wheel for cffi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command /home/ks/priroda-venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c                                         'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7c3p58ht/cffi/setup.                                        py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replac                                        e('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec                                        '"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-an_3ux86 --python-tag cp34:
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
  running build_ext
  building '_cffi_backend' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/c
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototype                                        s -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-securit                                        y -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include                                        /ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/ks/priroda-venv/inc                                        lude/python3.4m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/c/_cffi_back                                        end.o
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.
  error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for cffi
  Running setup.py clean for cffi
Failed to build cffi

Installing collected packages: cffi, cryptography, social-auth-core, social-auth                                        -app-django
  Running setup.py install for cffi ... error
    ERROR: Complete output from command /home/ks/priroda-venv/bin/python3.4 -u -                                        c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7c3p58ht/cffi/setu                                        p.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().repl                                        ace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'ex                                        ec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-x424l4as/install-record.txt --single                                        -version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ks/priroda-venv/in                                        clude/site/python3.4/cffi:
    ERROR: running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/recompiler.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/setuptools_ext.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/commontypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_cpy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/api.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/vengine_gen.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/model.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/error.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/ffiplatform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/verifier.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/pkgconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/cffi_opcode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/backend_ctypes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/cparser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_include.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/parse_c_type.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/_embedding.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    copying cffi/_cffi_errors.h -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/cffi
    running build_ext
    building '_cffi_backend' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/c
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototy                                        pes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-secur                                        ity -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/inclu                                        de/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/ks/priroda-venv/i                                        nclude/python3.4m -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/c/_cffi_ba                                        ckend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
                     ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "/home/ks/priroda-venv/bin/python3.4 -u -c 'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-7c3p58ht/cffi/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-x424l4as/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/ks/priroda-venv/include/site/python3.4/cffi" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-7c3p58ht/cffi/
```

What could be done about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing ffi headers which are contained in libffi-dev

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Comment: Thank you! This sorted the problem out!